# attaching options list to focused select

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have these very large drop down lists (1500) items.  I have to use a lot of these large drop downs on a single page (1500 items per list, 4 lists per object, 150 objects per page).  All of these lists are the same per object.

Unfortunately the client is demanding this structure, so I am looking for a good way to create the 4 drop down lists and reuse them depending on the select box they are focused on.

The lists are being created in razor:

```
var list = ViewData["List"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectEnumerable = null;

if(list != null)
{
    selectEnumerable = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.Text,
        Value = x.Value.ToString()
    }).OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value));   
}

@Html.DropDownList("List", selectEnumerable)
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Do you mean you want when someone opens a dropdownlist, it fills it, but if someone opens one of the others, it clears the previous list and fills the selected one? I reckon that'd be a bit clunky for the user if they have an older machine.

Comment: @malik yes.  I might add that the dropdownlists are jquery comboboxes.  If this is too clunky, are there any other suggestions? Bc as it is, this page is way to slow.

Comment: either the server does the work, or the user's computer does the work. Depending on how fast the user machines are, you could offload this to them. But if it isn't, the user might feel like their browser has hung whilst the browser loads all the select boxes from an array.

Comment: The server is slow, we have tried a combobox that pings the database and it takes a few seconds to retrieve the list.  The front end becomes very slow when there are 200,000 nodes present.

Comment: I'd advise against 'moving' your select options on click. Adding and removing that many nodes would probably cause a bit of lag. See my answer for a possible solution you could try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it client-side, then one way to do it is to use jquery's `clone()`

So what you would do is, load the first `select` box server side like you have in your question. Then create 3 other `select` list but leave them empty, and give them a `class` attribute which is the same, e.g. "my-list-class". Finally, in your script file, you could create a function that's run once at start up.

**JS**:

```
  function LoadSelectLists()
  {
    var list = $("#sel1 > option").clone();
    $('.my-list-class').append(list);
  }
```

**Html**:

```
<select id="sel1">
  <option value="a">opt1</option>
  <option value="b">opt2</option>
  <option value="c">opt3</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2" class="my-list-class"></select>
<select id="sel3" class="my-list-class"></select>
<select id="sel4" class="my-list-class"></select>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2WDcz/